# radio button in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to save the radio button value to a state.

I have a form of a text box and few radio buttons. i want to save the text field and radio button value so that i can render these values in a table.

```
export class AddColumns extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
        this.state={
            newItemInput: '',
            selectedValue: '',
            buyItems :['Development','Testing']
        }
      }

  handleChange(value) {
    this.setState({
          ...state,
          selectedValue: this.state.selectedValue
    });
  };

  change (event){
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]:event.target.value
    });
    console.log("button clicked",this.state);
  };

 render(){
      return(
        <div className="container">
          <div className="form-group">
              <label className="sr-only" htmlFor="newItemInput">Add New Item</label>
              <input type ="text" ref ={input => this.newColumn = input} name="newItemInput" placeholder="Modules" value = {this.state.newItemInput} className="form-control" 
                      id="newItemInput" onChange={event => this.change(event)}/>
            </div>

            <div className="k-form-field" value={this.state.selectedValue} onChange={this.handleChange}>
              <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" className="k-radio" />
              <label className="k-radio-label">RadioButton 1</label>

              <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" className="k-radio" />
              <label className="k-radio-label">RadioButton 2</label>

              <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" className="k-radio" />
              <label className="k-radio-label">RadioButton 3</label>
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Add</button><p>{this.state.messgae}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
);
}
```

I am not able to get the radio button value, please help

Comment: Any error u getting?

Comment: And where are you values on inputs? You have value and handler on parent div, instead of input elements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some correction.

1. You are missing `form` tag wrapping input control
2. on form submit define  event handler which will receive form data.
3. attach onChange event handler to radio button
4. attach `value` attribute to radio button having some value

Your render with above changes:

```
     render() {
        return (
          <div className="container">
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
            <div className="form-group">
//.....
              <input type="text" ref={input => this.newColumn = input} name="newItemInput" placeholder="Modules" value={this.state.newItemInput} className="form-control"
               //.....
            </div>

            <div className="k-form-field" >
                <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1" className="k-radio" onChange={this.handleChange}/>                                        
                                                 type="radio" name="radio" value="radio2" className="k-radio" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
              //.....

              <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio3" className="k-radio" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
              //.....
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <button type="submit"className="btn btn-primary">Add</button><p>{this.state.messgae}</p>
            </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        );
      }
```

Handler :

```
handleSubmit=(event)=>{
    console.log('A form was submitted: ' , this.state); //form data
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event);
  }
```

**Radio button handler:**

```
handleChange=(event)=> {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      selectedValue: event.target.value
    });
  };
```

Working **[`codesandbox`](https://codesandbox.io/s/k2km5kxpkr)**

Comment: Hi Riyaj, Thanks for the help, but are you getting the value of radio button??
Previously the form was working but i m unable to save the radio button value in the sate.

Comment: @bisnubiswal I have updated answer with sandbox code.Please check it

Comment: Hi RIYAZ, i am able to get value as "on", but how can i know which radio button is clicked, so that i can print that button name in the table? need help.

Comment: my bad,I have updated . codesandbox link . https://codesandbox.io/s/k2km5kxpkr . `value` is missing

Answer (score 2):

You have to call onChange on the radiobutton itself instead of the div that wrapps them all.

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" className="k-radio" onChange={this.handleChange} />
```